# Is there any way to find screen size in dp (not px) in Ionic/Angular/Cordova stack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, web-applications, ionic-framework

I know how to find dimensions in pixels both inner, outer, browser etc in Javascript using document, window and other objects..

Problem is, the returned width and hight are in px not in dp.

Lets say if screen is small enough that something is too big to fit I wanna hide some elements. And I wanna make it in a way that I remove elements in specific order (some are more useful, other are for additional info) until everything fits screen both horizontally and vertically (no scroll).

So I would get the screen size and ng-if remove objects from window until remaining objects sizes in pixels added together would be less then window.innerSize. Works well on desktop where pixel is pixel.

BUT, here comes the problem. On mobiles there is often a ratio of real screen pixels and displayed pixels. Eg. lets say a block is 300px high in css (height: 300px !important) but its 700 pixel high on actual device (measured using developer mode click on his bottom). I realize some is due to extra pixels on screen outside of app, like staus bar on top, but rest is in dp to px ratio of a screen.

How would you approach this problem, if there is no solution to original question of finding the dp dimensions of window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it, when you are using Cordova you have 
window.devicePixelRatio 
available for you.

And it comes to play just nicely. Use window.innerHeight to get actual height of everything inside window (ALSO works with keyboard overlaying your app!). 
For each element its height on screen is his_css_height * window.devicePixelRatio.

Translates exactly to what i wanted.

Sorry to answering my own question here but I spent almost 3 hours searching for an answer, and I decided to post here and then continue my search. Just became aware of this, hopefully it helps someone else :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

Comment: That is already known, found it on multiple threads :) Problem is, it's Java code. And application is being made for 3 different platforms (maybe more later on). I would prefer solution written in JavaScript not Java so I can use it on every platform.

Comment: he is asking for a solution in cordova js not in java